# Spring AOP Limitation when advised method calls methods on target

Tags: spring.net, spring-aop

My use case is to log every method call on an object.
After adding a method interceptor on the target object, I call the method `Foo`. This method `Foo` calls a method `Bar`. Only the method `Foo` will be logged.

```
class MyClass {
   public void Foo() {Bar();}
   public void Bar() {}
}
```

Reading the Spring documentation, I have found a sentence that explained why I cannot implement what I want. From Spring documentation (page 146):

> Please note that in both cases a target method implementation that calls
>   other methods on the target object will not be advised.

Am I missing something here? Or is this really a Spring limitation?

Comment: Please give us a link to that documentation, not a page number.

Comment: html documentation: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxy-mechanism

Comment: pdf documentation: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/pdf/spring-net-reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A start of solution...

http://www.digizenstudio.com/blog/2007/05/29/the-self-calling-limitation-in-spring-aop-and-one-unintrusive-solution/

EDIT
Finally, I decided to switch to Castle AOP. They propose a class proxy that feets my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AspectJ weaving that will not have any such limitations.

Comment: No you can't - this question relates to Spring_.net_ and not Spring for Java.